# What percentage of US carriers do fuel hedging?

Tags: fuel

What is the percentage of US carriers that are hedging fuel? Who are they, other than Delta who still owns a refinery?

Comment: What research have you done to find this answer on your own? Showing that effort and why what you've come up with so far isn't satisfactory for you is one of the requirements for posting here... [tour] [help]